# Solrj Query limit

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

My application fired Solr query which is of very long length, All i wanted to know is there is a limit for the query which SolrJ allows or its unlimited.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lucene, this is typically restricted to 1024 clauses of [`BooleanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html). You can increase this by calling `BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(...)`.

Comment: BooleanQuery you mean is the number of Logical(AND, OR) operators in the query. Right?

Comment: Operator is something that joins two clauses. E.g. query `+foo:1 +bar:0` would have two clauses, one for `foo` and another for `bar`.